# Find one non-diagonal minimum element from a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, min

Is there a shortest way to find the minimum of non-diagonal elements of the matrix along with its index in matlab.

If A= [1 2 3; 4 1 3; 4 4 4]; then i want to return the index of the minimum non-diagonal element. Here that will be 2 in the first row and second column. So, I want to return (1,2). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a fully vectorized alternative try

```
B = (A + diag(Inf(size(diag(A)))));    % put Inf on diagonal
[~,ndx] = min(B(:));                   % get the linear index of the minimum value
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A),ndx);          % get row, column of corresponding to linear index
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for k=1:size(A,1)
    A(k,k) = inf;
end
[row,col] = find(A==min(A(:)))
```